# How to prevent missing entries in .bash_history? (Possibly due to lack of disk space)

Tags: bash, debian, command-history

I just noticed that a lot of entries are missing from my bash command history (the .bash_history file).

I'd like to know:

- if there is a way to find out why commands are missing from the file (like a lack of disk space; I could not find hints in /var/log/syslog)
- if there are ways, issues or ongoing work to make sure that the bash history always *reliably* includes all executed bash commands - for example by copying a backup of the latest .bash_history file before overwriting it, doing so after *every* executed command and having a filesize-buffer in case disk space gets too low

The .bashrc file already has HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE set to very large values. I have backups of the .bash_history file.

Comment: What says `shopt histappend`? If is not set the last shell to close overwrites whatever other shells have added.

Comment: It says `histappend      on`. If that isn't the default setting that would be yet another problem.

Comment: If you `diff` the backups, do they only differ at the end or also at the beginning and/or middle of the files? Also what are te outputs of `sudo grep -r '^HIST' /etc/*` and `grep '^HIST' ~/\.*`?

Comment: It sadly looks like there's no overlap: the earliest commands of the current .bash_history file aren't in any of my backup files. I made the last backup of it a not-too-long while before the first command of the current one. It's mostly commands a short while after upgrading to Debian 10 that are missing now. Outputs:
`/etc/skel/.bashrc:HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth
/etc/skel/.bashrc:HISTSIZE=1000
/etc/skel/.bashrc:HISTFILESIZE=2000
/etc/sysstat/sysstat:HISTORY=7` &
`/home/username/.bashrc:HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth
/home/username/.bashrc:HISTSIZE=100000
/home/username/.bashrc:HISTFILESIZE=200000`

Comment: The issue doesn't seem to be caused by lack of disk space (created a bash bug report). Recently, lots of bash history entries were missing after a restart after a kernel upgrade (a Debian 11 upgrade) and it doesn't look like I was scarce on disk-space (nor did it display a warning at the time or afterwards). It wasn't a restart due to a freeze/crash either this time. Moreover, Vorta/borg backups for a few weeks are missing even though the target location has enough disk space and I configured Vorta to not prune these and I haven't deleted them. Backups were carried out again after the restart.

Answer (score 1):

The command history of your current shell is written to .bash_history when you close the shell. Therefore, while usually all recent commands are accessible from the shell, they are not yet added to the .bash_history file.

Comment: Thank you. That's another problem. Hundreds of older commands are missing.