# How to find out what caused a deletion of .bash_history entries during a specific timespan (to prevent it from happening again)?

Tags: bash, debian, logs, command-history

Lots of entries were missing from my ~/.bash_history. I made frequent backups of that file so I determined a timespan of a few hours during which the file must have been deleted or emptied.
Which ways are there to find out what caused this - how would you try finding out?

Comment: For me the reason is usually a full disk/partition. Otherwise, `bash` cannot save its history when killed instead of cleanly existed (`exit` or ^D).

Comment: Is there a log message persisted in Debian shortly before the disk/partition is full? Do you know if there is an issue about always reserving a few kB of disk space for .bash_history entries updates? Why would empty the file rather than simply not writing new entries to it?

Comment: The most common reason I experience is that I have multiple `bash` logins running concurrently.  The history entries from the session that logs out first will be overwritten by the entries from the session that logs out last.

Comment: You can get bash to append to `$HISTFILE` rather than overwrite it with `shopt -s histappend`.   Also relevant: the `ignoredups` and `erasedups` options for bash's `$HISTCONTROL` variable.   See `man bash` for details on these.   BTW, you can tell bash to write its history file at any time with `history -w` (overwrite) or `history -a` (append).   run `help history` in bash for more.

Comment: @cas I already had `shopt -s histappend` in ~/.bashrc before this happened; HISTSIZE is large enough too. (While helpful, it wasn't the cause in this case.) Furthermore I see no reason why this shouldn't be there by default. By default no history entries should ever be lost (incl. via measures such as always having a few kB of disk space reserved for these entries, a maximum bash-history-filesize [with early-warning and dedup once the filesize gets close to max of at least many MB by default] plus they should have timestamps).

Comment: Lack of disk space doesn't seem to be the (only?) reason...looks like it also occurred after a restart after a kernel upgrade without too little disk space. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/582401/233262